# Unable to run App in Visual Studio 2015 emulator for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-emulator

I have installed Xamarin SDK and VS2015. From "New Project" I have created "Android Blank Project" and now it builds successfully.

When I hit F5 to run using simulator it load simulator successfully but it does not run application inside.

It gets stuck after this line in output windows:

> 1>C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe
> 4 "C:\Users\test\documents\visual studio
> 2015\Projects\App2\App2\bin\Debug\App2.App2-Signed-Unaligned.apk"
> "bin\Debug\App2.App2-Signed.apk"

I tried all given solution like
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools key, Path value, in the registry, pointing to the Android SDK root directory. But no luck.

Is it an issue of pre-configured virtual devices Android_Accelerated_x86 API23?

[image]

Comment: did you check answers at [Xamarin - Visual Studio stuck at zipalign.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720602/xamarin-visual-studio-stuck-at-zipalign-exe?rq=1) ?

Comment: also, can you try "Build -> Deploy Solution", still the same? (I had a case once when I could run an app manually after deployment, but could not run it via Build -> Debug)

Answer (score 0):

There could be many solutions as listed in Other related question posts.

I resolved it using one below -

`Open Android Emulator Manager`

`Start Android Virtual Device`

```
Once emulator is ready then run your application.
```

It works.
[image]